# Mock a GPS path a set distance away from a point

Tags: java, android, gps, android-gps

I am developing an app that uses information from the API of the local bus services. 
As I don't have access to the bus's GPS system, I can't actually track the bus I'm wondering how I would go about mocking the bus's location.

I have the times that the actual bus is due at each stop so for example if a bus is due in 6 minutes I could estimate the speed the bus is travelling at and place it on map, the calculated distance away from the bus stop, but it would need the bus to be coming from the right direction ie mock the bus path.

I don't know if it's possible and if so how would I go about it.

I'd really appreciate any help/ideas I can get!

Answer (score 0):

I would not use GPS in this case.

If you know the path of the bus and therefor the distance the bus has to travel between two stops, the time the bus left the stop and the time it need to the next stop, you can then divide the distance of the path by the time the bus needs and then "move" it along the route depending on the time till it arrives (kind of like a status bar).

Then plot the path on the map and a dot moving on it. 
This should be easier then actually plotting GPS coordinates that you have to calculate for the whole path.